# Why can't I Resize/Move in GParted?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, gparted, boot-partition

I have a 12.04 LTS system running on my PC with a 320 GB hard drive.

Unfortunately, I need to use Windows 7 in my lab. I tried doing this using a virtual machine (VirtualBox and VMware) but it was not good enough. I want to make a partition on my hard drive so when the computer starts I'll choose between Windows 7 and 12.04.

I tried using Gparted, but for some reason I'm not getting the Resize/Move option.

There must be a way that I can do this without formatting and installing everything again.

Answer (score 14):

To be able to resize/move partitions, the partitions must not be in use.

Boot from a liveCD or liveUSB, make sure no partition is mounted then launch Gparted and create the necessary partition.

After installing Windows you'll have to recreate Grub. The easiest way is to boot again from the live USB, install boot-repair with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair` and do a recommended repair.

Comment: still doesnt work, it only resizes the partition by 48 mb which is not enough to install win7

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: here you go http://askubuntu.com/questions/488656/create-new-partition-for-windows