# How to split the disk partition having Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to create partition of my Hard Disk but the partition contains Ubuntu installed in it. I have GParted installed but since the partition contains Ubuntu I can't unmount. Is there any way I can create partition without losing the files that I have and with ubuntu still lying there?

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/18523/169736

Comment: Note that [you must run GParted from a live CD/DVD/USB system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/249808/why-cant-i-resize-move-in-gparted), like the system you used to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a live CD. Manipulating partitions can't be done while mounted unless you used LVM (and even then there could be some problems).

Comment: What is a live CD? How do I get it? Is it something that I could do with Pen Drive as a substitute to Live CD

Comment: @PrakashGautam The LiveCD is the disk you would use to install Ubuntu.  Yes you can use a USB/Pendrive as the live media as well as long as you have Ubuntu installed on it. You can download it from [Ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).... [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) are the instruction on how to create a LiveUSB.  Boot into the liveUSB then select "Try Ubuntu" then you can use gparted to resize the Ubuntu partition. Make sure you have backed up any data in the unlikely event that gparted errors.

Comment: I did exactly you did. But now I can't mount existing partition. Right Click>> Mount doesn't help either.

Comment: @PrakashGautam you don't need to mount anything. Actually mounting stuff will get in the way. Just resize/move your partitions the way you like and reboot the system.

Comment: I did shrink the partition but couldn't create new as it restricted of more than four partitions because I had very small partitions existing already. Now I've rebooted and want to move files out of already existing smaller partition but can't mount it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't able to resize or delete a partition using gparted if it was mounted.

You need a ubuntu live disk to unmount the partition where ubuntu is installed.

Comment: yes,you can create bootable ubuntu pendrive using unetbootin software.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps:

- Boot with Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB,
- Start GParted, select the partition you want to resize (here, that would be your Ubuntu root partition), [if you have a swap partition, switch it off; also if you have some mounted partitions, an unmount might be necessary]
- From the *Partition* menu select *Resize/Move*,

[image: snap1]

- Drag the slider or specify the new size manually, and click the <kbd>Resize/Move</kbd> button,

[image: snap2]

- Right click the *unallocated* space and select new,

[image: snap3]

- Specify the partition type (primary, logical, extended), file-system type, and other if required/desired, (**Set Align to "MiB"**) and click <kbd>Add</kbd> button,

[image: snap4]

- Apply the operations.

[image: snap5]

[[GParted in action screenshots]](http://gparted.org/screenshots.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a pendrive by using Unetbootin from unetbootin.sourceforge.net/‎
Simply follow the instructions, then set the boot order of your computer to have usb first, then turn the pc off, then insert pen drive, and reboot, and it will boot from the pendrive and allow you to repartition the drive